# Reading a .CSV file and created directories according to values

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to call a stored procedure and store the output in a CSV file. Using the same script, I'm intending to read the csv and use the values in particular columns to create directories in which I'll move files into. However, I require assistance creating the initial base code.

## An example record from the csv file:

Headers: Person      Category      Subcategory      Date          File

Values:  Bob         Human         Male             20191023      C:\Temp\Bob.jpg

## Workflow:

For each row in the SQL output;

- Create in the output folder a Person sub-folder if that does not exist
- Create in the Person sub-folder a category folder if that does not exist
- Create in the category sub-folder a subcategory folder if that does not exist
- Create in the sub-category sub-folder a date folder if that does not exist.  (The document date will be YYYYMMDD format).
- Copy the document files from there source location to the document date folder.

Current code:

```
#Variable Parameters
## Do not add final backslash to directory path
    $FilePath="C:\Temp\Output"

#Date Parameters
    Echo "Getting date & time"
        $GetDate=Get-Date
        $DateStr = $GetDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        $TimeStr = $GetDate.ToString("HHmm")

#SQL Connection & SP Execution
    Echo "Establishing SQL Connection"
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
        $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

#Run Stored Procedure
    Echo "Running Stored Procedure"
#Return Row Count Print from SP
    Echo "Row Count:" #This result with be printed via the SP
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = "[SCHEMA].[STOREDPROCEDURE]"
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
        $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

#Close SQL Connection
    Echo "Closing SQL Connection"
        $SqlConnection.Close()

#Output File
    Echo "Outputting File"
        $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV -notype "$($FilePath)\$($DateStr)_$($TimeStr)_Export.csv"

#Finished Exporting .csv File
    Echo "File Exported to Output Directory"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the whole path with just one `New-Item` call, like this:

```
$rootPath = 'D:\Persons'
#import your csv file and loop through the results
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\persons.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # create the path to output copy the file to
    # [System.IO.Path]::Combine() can combine 4 childpaths in one go
    $subPath  = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($_.Person, $_.Category, $_.Subcategory, $_.Date)
    $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $rootPath -ChildPath $subPath

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $fullPath -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $fullPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $_.File -Destination $fullPath -WhatIf
}
```

If you are satisfied with the results shown in the console, remove the `-WhatIf` switch to actually start copying files.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
# Import the CSV File    
$CSVData = Import-CSV -Path C:\Temp\file.csv

# For each record in the CSV file
$CSVData | foreach-object {
    # Build the personpath string
    $PersonFolder = "C:\$($_.Person)"

    # Test if the path (!NOT) exists
    if (!test-path $PersonFolder){
        # Create the person folder
        new-item -path $PersonFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    }

    # Build the category path string (adding to the person folder path)
    $CategoryPath = "$PersonFolder\$($_.Category)"

    # Test if the path (!NOT) exists
    <Code Here>

    # Create category folder...

    # Create date folder etc. etc. etc. 
}
```

Hope that gives you some ideas.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thank you for this, this is a step in the right direction for sure.

I'd prefer to do this in an if, else statement. E.G:

'# Test if the path exists
         if (test-path $PersonFolder)
            
            Else # Create the Person folder
              new-item -path $PersonFolder -ItemType Directory -Force}'

What would go in the if, to enter the next directory?